# Set Angular 6 App Base Start Up URL With Query String Parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

I need to set the initial start up URL of an Angular 6 App to include query string parameters. The app config depends on getting the values of these query string parameters on start up.

They have to be query strings, can't be path variables.

Must follow a pattern like: localhost:4200/?name=emerfan&ip=123

I have tried using the Router and Paths, and I have tried using Location to redirect the AppComponent in the ngOnInit method, to no avail.

e.g.

```
ngOnInit() {
this._location.replaceState('/?name=emer&ip=123');
}
```

and

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '?name=emerfan', component: AppComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/?name=emerfan', pathMatch: 'full'}];
```

The first doesn't work because app is not reloaded with the queryStrings to fulfill the config and the second doesn't work because it seems the config has already been created and is not recreated when the route redirect happens..

Is there a setting to set the base path in an Angular App with Query String parameters?

Comment: Do you the parameters just on initial load, or do you need to have them everywhere through navigation?

Comment: Just on initial load, there is only one page so no further navigation

Comment: So why do you have to modify the routes? You can just navigate to localhost:4200?name=emerfan&ip=123 and retrieve the query string params from your code, no? Why do you need to call replaceState after?

Comment: I need the app to start up on localhost:4200?name=emerfan&ip=123  without the user having to navigate anywhere

Comment: That can be a redirection that you set up server side then

Comment: That does not solve my problem

Comment: If you set up your nginx /Apache/nodejs/ production webserver to redirect `http://yoursite.com` to `http://yoursite.com/?name=emerfan&ip=123`. then the angular app will start with the query string parameters. This will not work for development though, but you can directly navigate to the correct url manually. Or maybe I completely misunderstood what you are after

Comment: Yeah it looks like I will have to do that, it's annoying that you can't initialize the app in this way